# How to create a popup window via href link for each row after calling database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Currently I have a table that displays various columns from an SQL database, including a count. I am trying to create something that will allow the user to click on that and a pop up box appears with a history of that (also from the database).

There are several things I've tried. I tried to do a href to another php file I had. While that loaded the data correctly, it opened a new webpage, which is what I did not want.

My current code is trying to do a popup box using javascript/jquery. But that is always showing it and also messing up the table.

Some code has been taken out

```php
#Original SQL database call is in this line
  echo('<table class="odds_table">');
  echo('<thead>');
  echo('<tr>');
  echo('<th>Date</th>');
  echo('<th>Teams</th>');
  echo('<th>WagerCount</th>');
  echo('</tr>');
  echo('</thead>');
  echo('<tbody>');
  while ( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    echo('<tr>');
    echo('<td rowspan="2">'.substr($row['GameDateTime'],0,10).'<br/>'.substr($row['GameDateTime'],11,8).'</td>');
    echo('<td>'.$row['VisitorTeamID'].'</td>');
    echo('<td rowspan="2"><a class="wagerhistory" href="#">'.intval($row['WagerCount']).'</a></td>');
    echo('<div class="wagerhistorytable" title="Wager History for '.$row['VisitorTeamID'].' @ '.$row['HomeTeamID'].'">');
    # This is where I do another database call to get the history
    echo('<table><thead><tr><th>Wagers</th><th>Time</th></tr></thead><tbody>');
    while ( $row = $wager_history->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
       echo('<tr>');
        echo('<td>');
        echo($row['Wagers']);
        echo('</td>');
        echo('<td>');
        echo(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$row['date_timestamp']/1000));
        echo('</td>');
        echo('</tr>');
      }
      echo('</tbody></table>');
 echo('<td>'.$row['HomeTeamID'].'</td>');
 echo('</tr>');
 }
echo('</table>');
```

And then my javascript file

```
<script>
$(".wagerhistory").click(function(event) {
  $(this).parent().parent().children(".wagerhistorytable").dialog({
    close: function( event, ui ) {
      $('.wagerhistorytable').dialog('destroy');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you opposed to using bootstrap? I have something set up in similar fashion using bootstrap modals.

Comment: @KamaranL, no not opposed to using bootstrap. I've never used it before, so I'm ignorant on that.

Comment: you want specific id data from database on users click button in bootstrap modal?

Comment: can you drop some output or screen shot.

Comment: @mohit I'm not familiar with bootstrap. But I want specific data from the database that was already entered.

Comment: I think you didn't  close your div tag.

Comment: @MichaelJester but you wrote you want in pop up window.

Comment: @MichaelJester, just to be clear. You want a separate popup to open for each row, or you want a single popup to open displaying all the rows?

Comment: @rrsantos, you're right. I closed the div tag, but it still appears.

Comment: @MohitKumar, yes. I want that data to appear in a pop up.

Comment: @KamaranL, yes. I would like each row to have a separate pop up box. So if I click the first row, a table for that specific game will appear. If I click the second row, then the data for that game will appear.

Comment: @MichaelJester can you try this ?

Comment: @MichaelJester, I made a [repl](https://repl.it/@KamaranLayne/Pop-Up-per-row) that will hopefully point you in the right direction. Of course, you must substitute your data with my dummy data where I have pointed out. Let me know if this helps or if I'm missing something.

Comment: @KamaranL This will definitely guide me in the right direction. Thank you! Just one quick follow up question. If I wanted to have links instead of buttons, would I go about it the same way?

Comment: I updated the repl to change the button to a link. Will that work? If so, I'll post a cleaner version of the answer here for others to reference.

Comment: @KamaranL brooo (or gal), that is so clean. That is perfect!

Comment: @MichaelJester, much obliged. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case something happens to the [repl](https://repl.it/@KamaranLayne/Pop-Up-per-row), here's a cleaner version of the code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- include the bootstrap cdn links. 1 for CSS, 3 for JS. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
      /* cursor class because 'javascript:void(0)' and '#' in a link that
      does not direct me anywhere kinda bothers me. */
      .cursor {
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php 
      # i assigned the following variable to simulate the amount of rows you have.
      $totalRowCount = 7;
      $i = 0;
      while ($i < $totalRowCount) { 
        /* modal and trigger (buttons/links) are thrown inside the while loop.
        notice the iterator is appended to the data-target's id as well as the
        id for the modal being called. so if you use your $row['id'] in place
        of the $i, you can call each game's info separately. */ 
    ?>
      <!-- Modal Trigger -->
        <a class="text-primary cursor" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal<?=$i;?>">
          Row <?=$i;?> Info
        </a>
        <br />
        <br />
      <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal<?=$i;?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Game <?=$i;?></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <?php
                /* replace 'data for game $i' with your $row['data'], or whatever 
                info is going to populate the modals. */ ?>        
                Data for Game <?=$i;?>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    <?php 
      $i++; 
      } #end while ($i < $totalRowCount)
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

first create `anchor Tag` & Create one class `openModal` in `<a></a>` Tag. Use this class in `<script></script>` to get `data-id` value

```
<?php  

    $id = $row['admin_id'];  ?>
        <tr>
            <td>                                 
                <a class="btn openModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="<?php echo $row['admin_id']?>"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
?>
```

Place this code in the same page below.

```
<div style="margin-top:5%;" class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS (data-id=.. is passed here.)**

```
<script>
  $('.openModal').click(function(){
      var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
      $.ajax({
        url:"ajax_modal.php?id="+id,
        cache:false,    
        success:function(result){
          $(".modal-content").html(result);
      }});
  });
</script>
```

**ajax_modal.php** 
(Create one page in same directory ajax_modal.php. If you are looking to change this page name. Change in  tag too. Both are related.)

```
<?php 

// Get `id` from `<script></script>`
$id = $_GET['id'];

$sel_query=mysqli_query($conn, "select * from admin where admin_id='$id'") or die(mysql_error($conn)); 
$selrow=mysqli_fetch_array($sel_query,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>

<div style="margin-top:5%;" class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content"></div>

        //echo your php output you want
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wasn't me. Anyway, I tried this, but when I click the link, nothing happens. I'm trying to test it with just echo'ing Hello World. The box doesn't even pop up. Also, why are we doing an SQL connection in line 6 of the ajax php file?